# How Do I Update Two Columns With a Single Query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to update values of two columns (*default_setting_value*, and *default_setting_enabled*) in a single table (*v_default_settings*) based on the value of another column within the same table (*default_setting_subcategory*).  I'm still learning PostgreSQL, however, in my research these are the two UPDATE statements I have come up with.  I have tested them against the database, and they work individually.  **I would much rather prefer to do this in a single query - so how can I do that?**

**SQL QUERY #1**

```
UPDATE v_default_settings
SET default_setting_value = CASE
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'base' THEN '/usr'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'bin' THEN ''
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'call_center' THEN '/etc/freeswitch/autoload_configs'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'conf' THEN '/etc/freeswitch'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'db' THEN '/var/lib/freeswitch/db'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'dialplan' THEN '/etc/freeswitch/dialplan'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'extensions' THEN '/etc/freeswitch/directory'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'grammar' THEN '/usr/share/freeswitch/grammar'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'log' THEN '/var/log/freeswitch'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'mod' THEN '/usr/lib/freeswitch/mod'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'phrases' THEN '/etc/freeswitch/lang'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'recordings' THEN '/var/lib/freeswitch/recordings'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'scripts' THEN '/usr/share/freeswitch/scripts'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'sip_profiles' THEN '/etc/freeswitch/sip_profiles'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'sounds' THEN '/usr/share/freeswitch/sounds'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'storage' THEN '/var/lib/freeswitch/storage'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'voicemail' THEN '/var/lib/freeswitch/storage/voicemail'
END
WHERE default_setting_subcategory IN ('base','bin','call_center','conf','db','dialplan','extensions','grammar','log','mod','phrases','recordings','scripts','sip_profiles','sounds','storage','voicemail');
```

**SQL QUERY #2:**

```
UPDATE v_default_settings
SET default_setting_enabled = CASE
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'base' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'bin' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'call_center' THEN 'false'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'conf' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'db' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'dialplan' THEN 'false'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'extensions' THEN 'false'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'grammar' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'log' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'mod' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'phrases' THEN 'false'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'recordings' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'scripts' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'sip_profiles' THEN 'false'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'sounds' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'storage' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'voicemail' THEN 'true'
END
WHERE default_setting_subcategory IN ('base','bin','call_center','conf','db','dialplan','extensions','grammar','log','mod','phrases','recordings','scripts','sip_profiles','sounds','storage','voicemail');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the other column to the `SET` statement:

```
UPDATE v_default_settings
SET default_setting_value = CASE
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'base' THEN '/usr'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'bin' THEN ''
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'call_center' THEN '/etc/freeswitch/autoload_configs'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'conf' THEN '/etc/freeswitch'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'db' THEN '/var/lib/freeswitch/db'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'dialplan' THEN '/etc/freeswitch/dialplan'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'extensions' THEN '/etc/freeswitch/directory'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'grammar' THEN '/usr/share/freeswitch/grammar'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'log' THEN '/var/log/freeswitch'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'mod' THEN '/usr/lib/freeswitch/mod'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'phrases' THEN '/etc/freeswitch/lang'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'recordings' THEN '/var/lib/freeswitch/recordings'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'scripts' THEN '/usr/share/freeswitch/scripts'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'sip_profiles' THEN '/etc/freeswitch/sip_profiles'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'sounds' THEN '/usr/share/freeswitch/sounds'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'storage' THEN '/var/lib/freeswitch/storage'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'voicemail' THEN '/var/lib/freeswitch/storage/voicemail'
END,
    default_setting_enabled = CASE
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'base' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'bin' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'call_center' THEN 'false'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'conf' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'db' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'dialplan' THEN 'false'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'extensions' THEN 'false'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'grammar' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'log' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'mod' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'phrases' THEN 'false'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'recordings' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'scripts' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'sip_profiles' THEN 'false'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'sounds' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'storage' THEN 'true'
WHEN default_setting_subcategory = 'voicemail' THEN 'true'
END
WHERE default_setting_subcategory IN ('base','bin','call_center','conf','db','dialplan','extensions','grammar','log','mod','phrases','recordings','scripts','sip_profiles','sounds','storage','voicemail');
```

Comment: thanks that worked!  Now I just gotta format it for use in a Bash script.

Answer (score 2):

Using [array subscriptions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) will make it much cleaner

```
update v_default_settings
set
    default_setting_value =
        (array['/usr','','/etc/freeswitch/autoload_configs',...])[
            array_position (
                array['base','bin','call_center',...],
                default_setting_subcategory
            )
        ],
    default_setting_enabled = ...
where default_setting_subcategory in ('base','bin','call_center',...)
```

If you want a `case` then use the simpler syntax:

```
update v_default_settings
set
    default_setting_value = case default_setting_subcategory
        when 'base' then '/usr'
        when 'bin' then ''
        when 'call_center' then '/etc/freeswitch/autoload_configs'
        when 'conf' then '/etc/freeswitch'
        when 'db' then '/var/lib/freeswitch/db'
        ...
    end,
    default_setting_enabled = case
        when default_setting_subcategory in ('base','bin','conf',...) then true
        else false
    end
    ...
where ...
```

The second case can be much simpler using the `in` operator

Comment: Thanks.  I think the case helps me visualize it better.  Any reason why the array subscription would be the better approach?

Comment: @KismetAgbasi The array would get rid of the `case` verbosity

Comment: Using the case approach you originally suggested resulted in a syntax error.  Noticed you updated your answer while I was typing this.... :)  Will try my hands on the array approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally went with (at least that I could understand at the moment).  Posting it in case someone else finds it useful:

```
UPDATE v_default_settings
        SET default_setting_value = v.value,
            default_setting_enabled = v.enabled
        FROM (VALUES
                  ('base',          '/usr',                                        'true' ),
                  ('bin',           '',                                            'true' ),
                  ('call_center',   '/etc/freeswitch/autoload_configs',            'false'),
                  ('conf',          '/etc/freeswitch',                             'true' ),
                  ('db',            '/var/lib/freeswitch/db',                      'true' ),
                  ('dialplan',      '/etc/freeswitch/dialplan',                    'false'),
                  ('extensions',    '/etc/freeswitch/directory',                   'false'),
                  ('grammar',       '/usr/share/freeswitch/grammar',               'true' ),
                  ('log',           '/var/log/freeswitch',                         'true' ),
                  ('mod',           '/usr/lib/freeswitch/mod',                     'true' ),
                  ('phrases',       '/etc/freeswitch/lang',                        'false'),
                  ('recordings',    '/var/lib/freeswitch/recordings',              'true' ),
                  ('scripts',       '/usr/share/freeswitch/scripts',               'true' ),
                  ('sip_profiles',  '/etc/freeswitch/sip_profiles',                'false'),
                  ('sounds',        '/usr/share/freeswitch/sounds',                'true' ),
                  ('storage',       '/var/lib/freeswitch/storage',                 'true' ),
                  ('voicemail',     '/var/lib/freeswitch/storage/voicemail',       'true' )
              ) AS v(subcategory,value,enabled)
        WHERE v.subcategory = v_default_settings.default_setting_subcategory;
```

I am still very much appreciative of @siyual and @clodoaldo-neto for assisting with the previous answers.